# What is the standard way to represent fixed point numbers in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, quartus-ii, modelsim, binary

Is there a native type in VHDL language similar to std_logic_vector that allows one to create a signed or unsigned fixed point number for given length of fractional and whole parts? If so, can it be synthesized?

How does one see fixed point quantities in wave window in test bench? Does one need to create a variable of type real and then use it to represent the fixed point quantity after manual conversion?

Are there functions in VHDL 2008 for conversion to and from fixed point and VHDL real type?

Comment: There is no *standard* fixed point libraries (or representations) in VHDL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If You'd like to implement fixed point arithmetics in **synthesizable** VHDL you have two ways:

1. Do It Yourself. It's rather hard method, but it may depend on quantity and complexity of equations You want to implement. Generally every "variable" should have two parts (integral and fractional) made of `std_logic_vector`s. Of course You have to implement basic (addition, subtraction etc.) mathematical operations.
2. Just download and use package `fixed_pkg`, it implements signed and unsigned fixed point types and all basic math - more [here](http://studylib.net/doc/7978881/fixed-point-package-user-s-guide).

But first of all - do You **really** need fixed (or floating) point types? Most math could be done on `std_logic_vector`, just like we do in microcontrollers using `int` types.

EDIT:

Unfortunately, link to the libraries inside pdf guide from above link is dead. Someone delete the files. But it shouldn't be a problem - currently all `ieee_proposed` libraries are moved to standard VHDL2008, so just change the used standard in the properties of Your project.

Comment: Sadly if you follow the trail in the "more here" link, it leads to a dead end.

Comment: I have to draw mandelbrot set, and thus need them. What is difference between fixed_pkg and fixed_generic_pkg?

Comment: Why not just use std_logic_vector and make sure that it is shifted correctly before and after all arithmetic operations? I am surprised by your description of having to create two parts for every number.

Comment: @quantum231 If You use one `std_logic_vector` for every number (and just remember where is the "point") it will be exactly the same like using ordinary `int` in C.

Comment: @vicatcu What's the matter? There is a 15-page PDF in the link?

Comment: I am getting a lot of files showing on my mobile phone from this link. Will open once I get home.

Comment: OK, I have looked into the file, the main question I have is, if I am using IP blocks from Altera Quartus IP catalog for arithmatic functions, how will sfixed and ufixed map to them? probably these IP are not designed to be port maped to sfixed and ufixed.

Comment: @JakubRakus the first link in the PDF is a dead link: http://www.vhdl.org/fphld/vhdl.html -> leads to a 404

Comment: @vicatcu I see, someone delete the files, about year ago they was there... I've added an edit to my answer.

Comment: @quantum231 Unfortunately I've never use the IP blocks from Altera and don't know how they work.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the standard way to represent fixed point numbers in VHDL?

There is none.

"Fixed point" is an *interpretation* of a number. The waveform display *interprets* the binary vector in a certain way. I don't know whether you can change that interpretation (in Xilinx Vivado, you can, to an extend, with a click of your right mouse button...), but it's basically not worth much: For all means and purposes, you use fixed point numbers to be able to treat fractional quantities like integers.

Comment: Doesn't use of sfixed and ufixed amount to a standard method? After all this is what they were created for right?

Comment: no. The whole point in using HDLs is that you get the freedom to choose whatever format fits your application. Thus, anyone telling you "this is a standard format" hasn't understood that you parameterize your HDL design for your algorithm, not the other way around.

Comment: I think the words 'standard method' were meant as 'typical method' and not to mean 'defined by a standard' :-) You do get freedom to choose but people tend towards a few oft-used and familiar methods.

Comment: @TonyM **exactly** what I'm saying. If you chose something, because it's "often used", then you're not doing the "design follows requirements" dance, you're doing the "I'm lazy, give me something that might work, I'll buy the next bigger FPGA to make it fit and hope it'll run fast enough if I just throw money at the problem" dance of the modern programmer.

Comment: @MarcusMuller, I can see the point you're making though, being VHDL, I imagine you mean designer, not programmer :-) But the opposite extreme is custom formats and functions that save less then they cost in the learning curve of other engineers for code reviews, testing and for reuse in other designs. It's somewhere between those and choosing recognisable formats is a virtue when assessed against all things. I do sympathise with your attitude to waste and bad design.

Comment: "Fixed point" is a mapping of a mathematical concept to its representation in logic signals. I cannot see why referencing the same VHDL-type would be a drawback for designs using the same mapping. It makes IP interoperable. You are still free to define whatever you want, if you are better off with a non-standard representation like sign/magnitude. What's your point?